# SpriteKit sprite not following path correctly

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm currently converting my android game to iOS, and I'm trying to get a bat enemy to 'swoop' the player. I have the curve created in SpriteKit and it looks [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwwGB.png), however the bat does not appear to follow the line correctly, it disappears for a few seconds and then zips past the top right corner going upwards despite running an action.follow on a path that looks drawn properly. The path is attached to a shapeNode which follows the player.

Code:

```swift
func createPath(){
        //All x values are moved back 1 / 4 of the screens width due to the camera being 1 / 4 of the screens width ahead of the player, and y values are halved due to the player being in the centre of y axis
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: gameScene.frame.width * 3 / 4, y: gameScene.frame.height / 2)) //top right corner

        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: -(gameScene.frame.width / 3.5), y: gameScene.frame.height / 6), control1: CGPoint(x: gameScene.frame.width / 2,  y: -(gameScene.frame.height / 9)), control2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(gameScene.frame.width / 9)))
        //to = off screen
        //control1 3 / 4 across screen, slighly higher than player
        //control2 exactly on player (players node height is screen width / 4.5)

        followLine = SKAction.follow(path, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 3)

        viewLine.path = path
        gameScene.addChild(viewLine)
    }

    func update(dt: Double){
        if(GameScene.gV.distanceM == 4 && !run){//DistanceM is just a timer (seconds)
            run = true
            bat.run(followLine)
        }
        if run {
            /*time += dt//timer to reset bats position
            if time > 4 {
                run = false
                time = 0
            }*/
        } else {
            bat.position = CGPoint(x: gameScene.pigeonCam.position.x + gameScene.frame.width / 2, y: gameScene.pigeonCam.position.x + gameScene.frame.height / 2)//keep bat at top right of screen
        }
        viewLine.position = gameScene.pigeon.pigeon.position//get node to follow the player
    }
```

My best guess is that while moving the shapeNode appears to move the path it actually doesn't, if so, any other way I could get this path to "follow" the player

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I realised the node asOffset is referring to is the one that runs the action, so I put the bat at the top right corner of the screen and adjusted the values, my final values looked as so:

```swift
        let width = gameScene.frame.width
        let height = gameScene.frame.height

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) //top right corner
        //0, 0
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: -(width * 1.2), y: -(height / 3.5)), control1: CGPoint(x: -(width / 4),  y: -(height / 1.5)), control2: CGPoint(x: -(width * 3 / 4), y: -(height / 2)))
```

This makes the bat follow the line perfectly, though the visual representation of the line is messed up